# Word 2016: Problems with large documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I have a single Word document with about 300 pages text, tables, graphics, etc. Word has serious problems processing this document. Opening and saving is very slow. Word lags while working in the document. And most worse: It's bugy. Pages are sometimes not properly displayed or the formatting of the document breaks.

Any idea how to mitigate the problem? Will an upgrade to Word 2019 make things any better?

Comment: Upgrading won't solve this but I'm sure it can be fixed. How many MB is the document? It could be large or it could be a corrupted file. Knowing its size will help to understand what's going on here.

Comment: It's about 35MB. I'm already using compressed images and I can't get any lower without loosing quality.

Comment: You can backup the document firstly. Try to save it as other file formats. You can also treat it as a damaged document, follow the methods in the articles to have a try:[How to troubleshoot damaged documents in Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/word/damaged-documents-in-word).

Comment: Doesn't help...